# More efficient way to separate numbers in r?

Tags: r

I have a function that is doing that I want but is very inefficient and I wonder if there are a **more efficient** way to do that.

The thing that I want to improve is separate a number and save the data into different variables, then sum them.
The code I have is:

```
indep <- as.numeric()
first <- as.numeric()
sec <- as.numeric()
third <- as.numeric()
for(i in 1:nmat){
  first[i] <- as.numeric(substr(matrix[i], 1, 1))
  sec[i] <- as.numeric(substr(matrix[i],3, 3))
  third[i] <- as.numeric(substr(matrix[i], 4, 4))
  indep[i] <- sum(first[i],sec[i],third[i],na.rm=T)
}



> For example if I have the numbers(234,361) 
>     I want in first->(2,3), 
>     in second->(3,6), 
>     third->(4,1) and in
>     ind->(2+3+4=9,3+6+1=10)
```

> Numbers have more than 6 digits and with one point like 1.923442334,
>   also data is in a big matrix NxN

Hope you understand what I want, thank you.

Comment: you might try starting with `do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(as.character(c(234,361)),""),as.numeric))`

Comment: and rowSums... but why not `unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(c(234,361)),""),function(decomp){sum(as.numeric(decomp))}))` ? this would give `ind` vector.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers have each three digits, you can avoid string manipulation and use basic arithmetic. For instance:

```
    numbers<-c(234,361)
    #this will give you a matrix in which each column has the digits of each number
    myMatrix<-matrix((rep(numbers,each=3) %/% 10^(2:0))%%10,nrow=3)
    #obtain the sum of the digits:
    colSums(myMatrix)
```

This approach is orders of magnitude faster than every one that uses string manipulation.

Comment: Numbers have more than 6 digits and with one point like 1.923442334, also data is in a big matrix NxN , thank you for your help.

Comment: This is why it's a good to be as specific as you reasonably can when stating your problem ...